# VBA Factory method with Private Variables

Tags: vba, excel

So I Have a `Factory` Class with method `Create_product`

`Product` happens to have Private Variables that I would like to be set by `Factory` however if they are private how can I make `Factory` access them?

Preferably I want it to be impossible to change them after new instance of `Product` is created.

Answer (score 1):

**Friend**

Modifies the definition of a procedure in a form module or class module to make the procedure callable from modules that are outside the class, but part of the project within which the class is defined. Friend procedures cannot be used in standard modules.

**Syntax**

```
[Private | Friend | Public] [Static] [Sub | Function | Property] procedurename
```

The required procedurename is the name of the procedure to be made visible throughout the project, but not visible to controllers of the class.

**Remarks**

Public procedures in a class can be called from anywhere, even by controllers of instances of the class. Declaring a procedure Private prevents controllers of the object from calling the procedure, but also prevents the procedure from being called from within the project in which the class itself is defined. Friend makes the procedure visible throughout the project, but not to a controller of an instance of the object. Friend can appear only in form modules and class modules, and can only modify procedure names, not variables or types. Procedures in a class can access the Friend procedures of all other classes in a project. Friend procedures don't appear in the type library of their class. A Friend procedure can't be late bound.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a singleton class as is [1](http://www.newsroom.cz/excel-vba/79-makra/86-vba-singleton.html)

Create form module named Singleton:

```
Private SingleInsts As Collection
Private instCount As Double
Public isCalled As Boolean 

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Hide
    Me.isCalled = False
End Sub

Private Function setInstance(name As String) As Object
    Dim Obj As Object
    If SingleInsts Is Nothing Then Set SingleInsts = New Collection
    instCount = SingleInsts.Count
    ReDim singleNames(instCount + 1)
    Me.isCalled = True
    Select Case name
        Case "Example"
            Set Obj = New Example
        Case "Other"
            Set Obj = New Other 'etc. etc - Case ... for all classes
        Case Else    
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 800, Err.Source & "|" & Me.name & "." & "setInstance", name & " is not a classname"

    End Select
    Me.isCalled = False
    SingleInsts.Add Obj, name
    Set setInstance = Obj
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Function getInstance(name As String) As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    If (SingleInsts(name) Is Nothing) And False Then
        'this way only by error - when SingleInsts(name) doesn't exist 
        Set getInstance = setInstance(name)
    Else
        Set getInstance = SingleInsts(name)
    End If
End Function

Public Function errNew(errstr As String)
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 703, errstr 
End Function
```

This function has to be in all classes:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 If Not Singleton.isCalled Then Singleton.errNew TypeName(Me)
End Sub
```

And then call "factory" method to get object (an object can be instantiated only once - see getInstance method in Singleton)

```
Sub fo()
    set alfa = Singleton.getInstance("Example")
End sub
```